# python wkhtmltopdf to Generate pdf

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

I am able to generate the pdf using the Command Line wkhtmltopdf but when i use it in python lib

```
from wkhtmltopdf import WKhtmlToPdf

wkhtmltopdf = WKhtmlToPdf(
    url='http://www.wikipedia.org',
    output_file='a.pdf',
)
```

i get

```
'Exception: Missing url and output file arguments'
```

Comment: Your code seems quite different from the example included in the [github repo](https://raw.github.com/mreiferson/py-wkhtmltox/master/test_pdf.py).

Comment: I Used the Example from http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=wkhtmltopdf&version=0.1

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an issue with the current version. I had the same issues, and if you look at their Github [issues page](https://github.com/qoda/python-wkhtmltopdf/issues/5), someone posted the same issue two days ago.

This should have worked also, according to their documentation:

```
python -m wkhtmltopdf.main google.com ~/google.pdf
```

But instead I get:

`optparse.OptionConflictError: option -h/--header-html: conflicting option string(s): -h`

Since it's a wrapper, I'm guessing the underlying application was updated, but the wrapper has not been.

Comment: Calling the class like this seems to get past the error, but other errors reveal themselves:   "wkhtmltopdf = WKhtmlToPdf('http://www.wikipedia.org','a.pdf',)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem in typos and rewrited API in wkhtmltopdf/main.py

Right now API is:

```
from wkhtmltopdf import WKhtmlToPdf

wkhtmltopdf = WKhtmlToPdf('http://www.wikipedia.org','out.pdf')
```